# Validating url with http:www as optional using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate a url where the "http:www" is optional, so the yahoo.com and http://www.yahoo.com needs to be valid url but using the following regex does not take utl3 to be valid one .
How can I fix this ??

```
function checkUrlTest(url){
            var urlregex = new RegExp("^(https?:\/\/www\.)?(^(https?:\/\/www\.)[0-9A-Za-z]+\.+[a-z]{2,5})");

            return urlregex.test(url);
        }
        url3 = "yahoo.com";
        url4 = "www.yahoo.com";

        alert(checkUrlTest(url3));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/fy66p/

Solution reside here: **Negative Lookahead:**  http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead with the `www` case and you should get what you are looking for. Lemme know how it goes!

Hope it fits your needs `:)`

**code**

```
function checkUrlTest(url){

    // Try this
    var urlregex = new RegExp("^(?!www | www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$")

            return urlregex.test(url);
        }
        url3 = "yahoo.com";
        url4 = "www.yahoo.com";

        alert('===> ' + checkUrlTest(url4) + '===> ' + checkUrlTest(url3));
```

Comment: I am trying your demo with  `url4 = "www.yahoo.com/sss <> ' kk";` and this is returning as valid.

Comment: Still valid in urlregex.test("com.com.com.com");

Answer (score 1):

```
(http://)?(www\.)?[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,3}
```

In this regex, http://www.yahoo.com, http://yahoo.com and www.yahoo.com are all valid URLs

Answer (score 1):

Just check it out. All problems will resolve.

```
var rgx = /^\s*(http\:\/\/)?([a-z\d\-]{1,63}\.)*[a-z\d\-]{1,255}\.[a-z]{2,6}\s*$/;
```

Comment: This regex returns true for one word. i.e. rgx.test("domain")

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateUrl(value)
{
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(value);
}
```

if not try this:

```
(?i)\b((?:(?:[a-z][\w-]+:)?(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```